# Seaborn relplot not taking any parameters besides x, y, and data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to plot a graph using the seaborn library, but the relplot() function does not take more than 3 parameters: `x`, `y`, and `data`. I specifically want to add a `hue=''` to my graph but an error arises.

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style='darkgrid')

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')


data_BM = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Pandas Part 2\\bigmart_data.csv")
data_BM = data_BM.dropna(how='any')
data_BM = data_BM.reset_index(drop=True)
data_BM['Visibility_Scaled'] = data_BM['Item_Visibility'] * 100

# print(data_BM.head(10))
# print(data_BM.shape, end='\n\n\n')

sns.relplot(x='Item_MRP', y='Item_Outlet_Sales', hue='Item_Visibility', 
            style='Outlet_Size', col='Outlet_Size', data=data_BM[:200])
plt.show()
```

Is there a certian rule that I am not aware of?
The error that I get is `ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation minimum which has no identity`

Comment: What is `print(data_BM.head(10))` ?

Comment: @jezrael It displays the first 10 rows of the dataset. Like a preview of sorts

Answer (score 0):

This error is raised when you try to pass an empty array. Make sure that the data or(sliced data) you are passing is not empty anywhere.

Comment: Shouldn't the `data_BM = data_BM.dropna(how='any')
data_BM = data_BM.reset_index(drop=True)` take care of that already?

Comment: @NicholasFeruch, Empty array does not mean nan values. You should check if the data itself is not empty i.e. blank data maybe. Also, check it for data_BM[:200].